# How to export integration values to a data file?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, export, list-manipulation, quantum-computing

I'm calculating quantum mechanical expectation value for a very high order truncation value. But due to low ram, it gets hung each time. So I am trying to write those data to a .dat file into the HDD and then export and use them.
How can I do that?
my code:

```
mesh = funs[[1, 0]]["ElementMesh"];
trunc = 100;
Table[xt[n,m]=NIntegrate[funs[[n]]*funs[[m]]*x,Element[{x},mesh]],{m,1,trunc},{n,1,trunc}];

file0 = OpenWrite["Expt.dat"];
Table[Export[file0, 
   NIntegrate[funs[[n]]*funs[[m]]*x, Element[{x}, mesh], "TSV"], {m, 1, trunc}, {n, 1, trunc}];
Close[file0];
```

The last line returns a single coloumn of data, but I need a table as `Table[xt[n,m]=..]` is returning

Comment: Your code does not run. funs is not defined.  xt is calculated but never used. You overwrite your file.

Comment: I know. It's not the entire code but a part of it. I just wanted to know how to write xt into a data file as it's coming

Comment: You need OpenAppend not OpenWrite, this overwrites the file.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `Write` instead of `Export`. Here's the intuition: `Export` is usually used after a loop (or `Table`), not inside the loop (or `Table`). When `Export` is used inside a loop, the file name usually changes inside the loop.

If you prefer to use `OpenWrite`, you must use `Write` to add the data to the file. The intuition is when `Write` appears inside a loop we expect to see `OpenWrite` before the loop and `Close` after the loop, as you have done. When `OpenWrite` appears inside the loop, we expect to see the file name change inside the loop. Of course, there can be exceptions.

Here is an example using `OpenWrite`

```
file = OpenWrite["tmp.txt"];
Table[Write[file, NIntegrate[x^n, {x, 0, 2}]], {n, 3}];
Close[file];
Import["tmp.txt", "TEXT"]

(*  2.000000000000002
    2.6666666666666705
    4.000000000000007   *)
```

Here is one way to use `Export`.  In this example it *looks like* the `Export` comes before the loop, but the loop is *executed* before the `Export`.

```
Export["tmp.txt",
  Table[NIntegrate[x^n, {x, 0, 2}], {n, 3}], "TSV"];
Import[%, "Text"]

(*   2.000000000000002
     2.6666666666666705
     4.000000000000007    *)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. However, I was not seeking this answer. I want to write my result xt in a matrix/table form in a .dat file as it is coming after code execution. However, when I execute the last line of my above-mentioned program, it gives a single column of results. How to write it in a xt[n,m] form?